# Can CodeMirror change the background color of a section of Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

I have a programming language (called SPIN) that has a custom IDE that highlights the background of sections of code (marked by keywords at the beginning of a line), to help with visibility. (The highlighting scheme also changes with the different colored background)

Example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bpsu.png

I am attempting to develop an online IDE for this language using CodeMirror. However, I have not been able to find any information on how I would be able to change the background color on a section of code. There is a partial implementation of an editor on http://www.phipi.com/editspin/, without colored highlighting or background. It appears that CodeMirror wraps each line in a `<pre>` tag, with nothing to differentiate between lines.

Is there any way for me to implement this in CodeMirror? Or is there another editor framework that I could use to implement this?

Comment: CodeMirror has a method `addLineClass` that can be used to add any CSS class to any line (
http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_decoration)

Comment: Okay, that looks pretty helpful. Is there a way that I could loop through all the lines, checking for three specific characters (Such as PUB, PRI, VAR, etc), and then get that line's number so I can feed it to the `addLineClass`?

Comment: Okay, I found `doc.eachLine` which looks like it will work.

Comment: why not [write a specific mode](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi) for it? that's what modes are for.

Comment: Modes can't (sanely) style the background of text. `addLineClass` is what you currently have to use for this. You'll have to listen to change events and update the backgrounds of changed sections.

Comment: Starting with 3.19 modes can style the background: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#token_style_line